# Multiple formating conditions in JSON

Tags: css, json, sharepoint, conditional-formatting

I am trying to use a simple formatting for my SharePoint listby using JSON for formatting the color based on the row index and "approval status", a simple logic as follows:

```
 If the status is approved:
      for each devise the index by 2 and if the reminder is equal to 0 show a slightly lighter color
                                ,otherwise a darker color (pretty standard formatting)

If the status is not Approved
    if Status is Pending, use orange
    if status is Rejected, use red
```

coloring based on the row index works fine, and also the coloring for status works fine but cannot put these two together.

```
{
  "additionalRowClass": {
    "operator": ":",
    "operands": [
      {
      "operator": "&&", "operands": [
      { "operator": "==", "operands": ["[$_ModerationStatus]","Approved"] },
        "operator": "==",
        "operands": [
          {
            "operator": "%",
            "operands": [
              "@rowIndex",
              2
            ]
          },
          0
        ]
        ]
      },
      "sp-css-backgroundColor-neutralBackground",
      {
        "operator": ":",
        "operands": [
          {
           "operator": "&&", "operands": [
      { "operator": "==", "operands": ["[$_ModerationStatus]","Approved"] },
            "operator": "==",
            "operands": [
              {
                "operator": "%",
                "operands": [
                  "@rowIndex",
                  2
                ]
              },
              1
            ]
          },
          "sp-css-backgroundColor-noFill",
          ""
        ]
 
   
      
       
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my demo JSON code for your reference:

```
{
"schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass":"=if([$Status]=='Approved',if(@rowIndex%2==0,'sp-css-backgroundColor-neutralBackground','sp-css-backgroundColor-noFill'),if([$Status]=='Pending','ms-bgColor-orangeLight',if([$Status]=='Rejected','ms-bgColor-red',''))"
}
```

Test Result:

[image]

Comment: Mush simpler than nested JSON, thanks heaps, A few question please: not sure why you used $Status instead of $_ModerationStatus, I always though the "approval status" is a keyword and is fixed in all SP online versions, I was trying to replace the ms-bgColor-orangeLight with an arbitrary hexcode but did not work, do you know how? And another question, where shall I use ms-bgColor- and when sp-css-backgroundColor-